# How do I create a dynamic paint obstacle?

Tags: dynamic-paint

I want to make an obstacle for a brush so if the brush's paint goes outside the box it doesn't paint

[image]

My goal is to make any faces outside the box to not get painted, I tried giving the box a brush to erase paint and it kinda works, the block on the left still gets painted even though it's outside of it,

[image]